# Oracle nclob fields: remove newline (or carriage return) characters

Tags: database, oracle, replace, nclob

We have information in an Oracle db of type NCLOB, and I want to remove newline characters. This, for example, does not work:

```
MyNclobCell := REPLACE(MyNclobCell, '\n', '');
```

Do I have an answer below? Yes, yes I do!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Turns out that I needed to remove both the newline (\n, ascii: 10) and the carriage return (\r, ascii: 13) characters. To use my example above, the one line of code became two as follows:

```
MyNclobCell := REPLACE(MyNclobCell, chr(10), '');
MyNclobCell := REPLACE(MyNclobCell, chr(13), '');
```

I then got my NCLOB rows all in a single line, and pasted the contents into a spreadsheet and handed it off to the requestor, hooray!

**Update**: As per [Saurabh Patil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/578046/saurabh-patil)'s suggestion, an alternative syntax for code-golfers and single-line-likers:

```
REPLACE(REPLACE(MyNclobCell, chr(10), ''), chr(13), '');
```

Comment: Ok, then. This'll be the accepted answer unless someone has something better.

Comment: To use it in the query you can write it as: REPLACE(REPLACE(MyNclobCell, chr(10), ''), chr(13), '');

Comment: if the field has like below " line -1 has ABC and next line empty and then line 3 has DEF" ...the above command makes ABCDEF and how I can make as ABC DEF or ABC,DEF ?

Comment: @kanagaraj looks like a question worthy of it's own post.

Comment: @Jangles thanks for reply , I got solution for this issue and the below has worked REGEXP_REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(NOTES, CHR(10), ';'), CHR(13), ';'), '(;){2,}', ';'))